# JQuery create context menu from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my code, it works perfect without using array, and creates context menu on div, but now i want to create some context menu items from array. when i apply array it is showing all items of array in one line and separates by Comma (,) . but i need all items in different rows.

```
<div id="div_id" > </div>

$('#div_id").chromeContext({
    items: [

          { title: array,         onclick: function () { RToTb(array_name) } },
          { title: 'properties'   onclick: function () { abc();            } },
          { title: 'view'         onclick: function () { def();            } }

        ]
});
```

Comment: What's the Plugin URL?

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle.

Comment: ok wait, i will message both of you after create a fiddle. thank you in advance. i am beginner and new to fiddle may take some time

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/danial786zz/sobnwgeb/   check this